# Identify RTC CMOS battery connector

Tags: identification, connector

I'm trying to find the plug that fits into this socket. It's really, really small like 3.36 mm x 4 mm and the distance from pin to pin is like 1 mm.

It's the socket for an RTC BIOS battery in a **UP Squared** single-board computer. I thought any RTC BIOS cable with a battery from eBay would do, but this is smaller than those. I got the UP Squared on eBay for a really good price but the battery attached to a cable that plugs there is missing.

Manufacturer is in Asia and would charge me almost US$50 for shipping it, half the cost of what I paid for the single board computer :(

As you can see in the pictures, the smallest plug I have (a plug from a pretty small fan of a GPU) that is like 4.44 mm wide won't fit in.

I tried searching, but didn't have any luck finding anything.

[image: smallest plug I have won't fit in it. This one is like 4.55mm]

[image]

Comment: The most important thing that you need to measure is the pin pitch. Then you can _begin_ to narrow your search down. A major supplier of connectors like that is [JST](http://jst.com/home21.html). Browse their catalog and see if any of them match your measurements.

Comment: @JYelton thank you for the heads-up, I did messuare with a caliper and the distance from pin to pin is 1mm. Will do the search in website you suggested right now. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Cai You could buy a connector pair with the same pin pitch and replace the part on the PCB with your own.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for certain - will update answer if measurements come in. But, this [JST-2(PH)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/B2B-PH-K-S-LF-SN/455-1704-ND/926611) looks pretty similar. Mates with [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/PHR-2/455-1165-ND/608607).

I'd further support this guess by saying that JST-2(PH) is a really common battery (especially li-ion) connector, but before you go buying 10 reels, keep in mind this is just an assumption from visual inspection.

EDIT: Considering that connector is 2.00mm, definitely not it. However, does 1.25mm sound like it's within margin of human error? This [Molex connector](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0533980271/WM7606CT-ND/699080) has the same detent profile

Comment: Thank you Orotavia, I see they have a 2mm pitch, I'm sure mine have a 1mm pitch, this is encouraging, will try to find if they have a 1mm pitch version, as you said they do look like the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry, totally missed the pin pitch you listed! I'm having a hard time finding this little guy - Here's a link to all 1.00mm JST 2-pin connectors on Digikey, but none look quite right to me ... https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-headers-male-pins/314?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&v=455&pv1989=0&pv1790=6219&pv88=121326&sf=1&FV=-8%7C314&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25